# How to delete aws config dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

I have created dashboard and rules. I am not able to find the option for removing the dashboard. Rules i have deleted. Can anyone put forth his thought on that?

[recording- view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg3IT.png)

When i tried to delete the associated roles it says this [iAM Roles associated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQgXi.png)

And the recording i cant stop.

And the dashboard is showing this,
[dashboard-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTDJV.png)

The problem is i cant delete completely dashboard unlike other aws services. Second, will there be any charges incurred for the opened dashboard?
Any thoughts on that, is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no option to delete dashboard from management console currently. Please try to use aws command.

```
 aws configservice delete-configuration-recorder --configuration-recorder-name YOUR_CONFIGURATION_RECODER_NAME
 aws configservice delete-delivery-channel --delivery-channel-name YOUR_DELIVERY_CHANNEL_NAME
```

To check the YOUR_CONFIGURATION_RECODER_NAME and YOUR_DELIVERY_CHANNEL_NAME you can use the following commands:

```
aws configservice describe-configuration-recorders
aws configservice describe-delivery-channels
```

After deleting your delivery channel, you can delete IAM role (AWSServiceRoleForConfig). Please note the S3 bucket for AWS-config will still exist.

Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/index.html